# python and calculating the power of a number

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I was asked to calculate the cubed root of a number in python3 and used the following code:

```
import numpy as np          # numerical routines
def myfunct(x):
    return np.power(x,3./2.)

xStar = 4
print('Exact value at',xStar,' is in myfunc ',myfunct(xStar))
```

This is fine, however by accident I found the following works

```
import numpy as np          # numerical routines
def myfunct(x):
    return np.power(x,3./2.)

def anotherfunct(x):
    return pow(x,3./2.)

xStar = 4
print('value at',xStar,' is in myfunc',myfunct(xStar))
print('value at',xStar,' is in anotherfunc',anotherfunct(xStar))

N = 3
xpt = np.linspace( 8., 12., num=N )
print(xpt)
print(myfunct(xpt))
print(wrongfunct(xpt))
```

that seems to give the same answer, namely

```
[ 8.   9.5 11. ]
[22.627417   29.28096651 36.48287269]
[22.627417   29.28096651 36.48287269]
```

My question is, is pow() really the same as np.power() and, if so, would it be considered bad programming practice to use pow() over np.power() in numerical programming?

Comment: generally "cube root" means power of 1/3, "cube of square root" would be 3/2, not sure if you are using the number you intend to

Comment: looking to determine the sqrt( x^3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prehaps take a look at the documentation for both:

- [built in pow](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow)

> The arguments must have numeric types. With mixed operand types, the
> coercion rules for binary arithmetic operators apply.

- [np.power](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.power.html)

> Raise each base in x1 to the positionally-corresponding power in x2.
> x1 and x2 must be broadcastable to the same shape.

the main difference - as with most of the numpy functions compared to built in ones - is only relevant when you look at the types of values input. If you only expect to use single value inputs (calculate it for a single number only) then they will act identically, if you want to do the calculation for an array of inputs at once the built in `pow` won't be happy with that.

Comment: thanks, however I amended my question to reflect your comments, however it seems that I should be using np.power

Comment: @jim right, because numpy arrays do define [`__pow__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__pow__) method so it properly defines what should happen when you call the built in pow. In general if you are expecting to use numpy arrays then probably just use the numpy methods since that is the only option for things like `sin`, `log` etc, so it is nice for consistency but if the array can define the proper behaviour for built in functions they will.